# Find the shortest distance from the triangle with vertices $(1,1,0),(3,3,1),(6,1,0)$ to the point $(9,5,0)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have to find the shortest distance from the triangle with vertices in $(1,1,0),(3,3,1),(6,1,0)$ to the point $(9,5,0)$.

I cannot figure out how to do this. There are three possible cases: the minimum lies inside the triangle, on an edge or at a vertex. But what is a reasonable way to understand in which case we are?

Comment: Well it's either closest to any of the vertices (point-point distance), or it's near one of the edges (point-line distance). Whichever's closer.

Comment: @orion that's not necessarily true in 3 dimensions

Comment: I remark that both points $(1,1,0)$ and $(6,1,0)$ are in the plan $P:y=z+1.$

Comment: Yes, the test goes point-line-plane in 3D. Basically imagine inflating the vertices into spheres, edges into cylinders and the triangle into a pillow, to get the blob of constant distance from the triangle.

Answer (score 4):

The plane $\pi$ through $(1,1,0),(3,3,1),(6,1,0)$ has equation $y-2z=1$, so it is perpendicular to the vector $(0,1,-2)$. There is an only value of $\lambda$ for which:
$$ (9,5,0)+\lambda (0,1,-2) \in \pi $$
and that gives the projection of $P=(9,5,0)$ on $\pi$, that is the point on $\pi$ with the minimal distance from $P$. If we solve the previous equation, we have that the projection of $P$ on $\pi$ lies in:
$$ Q = \left(9,\frac{21}{5},\frac{8}{5}\right)=-\frac{39}{25}(1,1,0)+\frac{8}{5}(3,3,1)+\frac{24}{25}(6,1,0) $$
i.e. outside the triangle made by $A=(1,1,0),B=(3,3,1),C=(6,1,0)$. This gives that the solution is not inside $ABC$, so it is somewhere on the perimeter of $ABC$, maybe in a vertex. Among $A,B,C$, the closest point to $Q$ is $C$. Let we compute the squared distance of a point of $BC$ from $P$:

$$ \|t(3,3,1)+(1-t)(6,1,0)-(9,5,0)\|_{2}^{2} = 25+2t+14t^2 $$
The RHS is obviously an increasing function on $[0,1]$, hence the optimal point on the $BC$ edge is the vertex $C$. The same happens for the $AC$ edge, while on the $AB$ edge the winner is the $B$ vertex, so the solution is given by the vertex $\color{red}{C}$, with distance $\color{red}{5}$ from $P$.

Comment: How did you come to the equation y - 2z = 1?

Comment: @kvcwahley: you may find it by trial-and-error like I did or invert a matrix through gaussian elimination, Cramer's method etc. To find the equation of a plane through three non-collinear points is a standard problem in linear algebra.

Comment: "Among $A,B,C$, the closest point to $Q$ is $C$ and the second closest point is $B$. This gives that the solution is somewhere on the $BC$ edge" This is not true in general. Consider the triangle with vertices $A=(-10,0,0)$, $B=(10,0,0)$, $C=(0,1,0)$ and the point $Q=(1,-1,0)$.

Comment: If you know about cross-products of 3D vectors, you can make vectors parallel to two sides of the triangle, and their cross product will be a multiple of $(0,1,-2)$, from which you can quickly find an equation of the plane.

Comment: @Rahul: you are right. Answer updated.

Comment: My comment is still a counterexample to the updated answer.

Comment: @Rahul: all right, all right, fixed again.