# Given a single point in 3d space, and 3 points that make up a triangle, find the closest point in/on the triangle to the point.

Tags: vectors, triangles, 3d

Given point $(p,q,r)$ and 3 points which make up a triangle, find the closest point in the triangle to the point in space. From the triangle, we can find the equation of the plane $Ax+By+Cz+d=0.$

EDIT: I am trying to ask a similar form of my other question, but in a more general form. I need to program a solution to this problem for any scenario. See comment below

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the shortest distance from the triangle with with vertices in $(1,1,0),(3,3,1),(6,1,0)$ to the point $(9,5,0)$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1367563/find-the-shortest-distance-from-the-triangle-with-with-vertices-in-1-1-0-3-3)

Comment: @David maybe he wants to generalize his question asked ago to any point.

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki  Maybe. But it would then be appropriate to say so in the question. It would also be appropriate to say something about whether the previous question was adequately answered.

Comment: What we really need here is a lot more _context_, that is, what you know about the question already, what you have tried, how this question arose--was the earlier one a homework exercise that you got curious to go further with, do you need to write software to solve problems like this, etc.

Comment: @DavidK you are right. I think he posted the new question before he saw the answer of the last one. But,  answering  this question is better as it is more general.

Comment: @KhadijaMbarki Yes, it might be that (eventually) the other question is a duplicate of this one (and this is not a duplicate). Or maybe the questions should be merged. I figured it was important to indicate the relationship now, the details we can sort out later if needed.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to ask a more general way of solving it. I need to program a way to solve this type of problem. I have a triangle and  a point. I don't know if that point is going to be inside the triangle, above below ect. Currently what I have tried to do is project the point onto the same plane as the triangle. I know the distance to the projected point and the distance from the projected point to the triangle. This should be a right triangle and taking the distance for the hypotenuse should give me the right answer, but it is not.

Comment: @kvcwahley, the question is a lot better with the edit you made (because now we know why you need a general method). I recommend putting a link in the question back to the previous question, and then I'll delete my "duplicate" comment. It also appears that you have done a lot of work on this already for one particular case--if that's where the other question came from, it might be a good idea to copy some of that work into the other question, showing the numbers you got (and also showing how the hypotenuse came out wrong). You might be very close to an algorithm and just need a small fix.